# Can you infuse a breastplate with Arcane Propulsion Armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, artificer, artificer-infusions

A [Breastplate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/breastplate) is a type of Medium armor that is described as:

> This armor consists of a fitted metal chest piece worn with supple leather. Although it leaves the legs and arms relatively unprotected, this armor provides good protection for the wearer's vital organs while leaving the wearer relatively unencumbered.

Notably it does not include any gauntlets.

If an Artificer were to use the Arcane Propulsion Armor infusion on a Breastplate what would be the effect?

Would gauntlets be created to function with the armor, would the Arcane Propulsion Armor be lacking its gauntlets, or would the infusion be invalid?

Related:
[Does Arcane Armor provide gauntlets?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180739/60913)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Breastplate is fully compatible

I don't know whether everyone will agree with my reasoning, but I believe the [Arcane Propulsion Armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#ArcanePropulsionArmor) infusion explicitly guarantees that gauntlets are provided. Here is the relevant text:

> The wearer of this armor gains these benefits: [...] The armor includes gauntlets

My interpretation is that entirely explicitly, Arcane Propulsion Armor provides gauntlets. It's specifically listed as a benefit of wearing the armor that has the infusion. For comparison, here is a portion of the description of another infusion, the Armor of Magical Strength:

> This armor has 6 charges

I don't think anybody would interpret the Armor of Magical Strength as being an infusion which can only be applied to nonmagical armors that (somehow?) already have exactly 6 charges, but rather an effect of the infusion. With similar wording, "The armor includes gauntlets" is an *effect* of Arcane Propulsion Armor, not a requirement. Thus infusing a Breastplate with Arcane Propulsion Armor is possible, and doing so would provide the full benefits associated with Arcane Propulsion Armor's gauntlets.